# Double click event on object created at run time - Delphi

Tags: delphi, object, events, runtime

I have created a simple Delphi form with a button that, when pressed, creates a label object in run time. I have created an on double click event for the label that shows a message to the screen. The problem is that after creating the label, I have to double click on the form before the double click event works on the label. Obviously this is not ideal as I would like to be able to double click on the label and trigger the event without having to first double click the form.

Here is the code for my form:

```
unit Unit4;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MyLabelDblClick(Sender:TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    LabelObject: TLabel;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form4: TForm4;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LabelObject := TLabel.Create(Self);
  LabelObject.Left := 100;
  LabelObject.Top := 100;
  LabelObject.Width := 200;
  LabelObject.Height := 20;
  LabelObject.Visible := True;
  LabelObject.Parent := Self;
  LabelObject.Caption := 'My Run Time Label';
  LabelObject.Cursor := crHandPoint;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LabelObject.OnDblClick := MyLabelDblClick;
end;

procedure TForm4.MyLabelDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  showmessage('You double clicked My Run Time Label');
end;

end.
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this matter.

Comment: Assign `LabelObject.OnDblClick` inside the `Button1Click` event.

Comment: @LURD perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: If you assign the double click handler for the label inside the double click handler for the form, then you should not be surprised that the label only reacts to a double click after you double clicked the form.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yeah that  makes sense now, silly mistake haha. But learning all the time! Thanks so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that after creating the label, I have to double click on the form before the double click event works on the label.

Assign `LabelObject.OnDblClick` when creating the label, i.e. inside the `Button1Click` event.